# How do retrieve the command of the running processes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

So I am familiar with the answers on using WMI for the list of the names.
I have also looked at psutil and using tasklist.

However I cannot find any reference for the command line executed for the running process.

One example for WMI is:

```
import wmi
 
# Initializing the wmi constructor
f = wmi.WMI()
 
# Printing the header for the later columns
print("pid   Process name")
 
# Iterating through all the running processes 
for process in f.Win32_Process():
     
    # Displaying the P_ID and P_Name of the process
    print(f"{process.ProcessId:<10} {process.Name}")
```

How do I get the:

[image: Task Manager]

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: From within the running process: [GetCommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew). For an external process you're going to have to find and read the target process' PEB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is all you need:

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() != 'firefox.exe': continue
    print( ' '.join( proc.cmdline() ) )
```